# How I can get the BI type site created in sharepoint online 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, office365, sharepoint-online

I have some excel data with multiple sheets, on which I need filtering and displaying the interactive reports to multiple web pages in SPO 2013.

For this I want to create a business intelligent site in sharepoint online 2013  to leverage the PPS(Performance point services, scorecards etc from BI features).

I don't see that option(while creation of site under enterprise tab -> Business Intelligent) available so far in sharepoint online.

though, on Prem if I go to central admin, I have this option, but I want to create this in SP OL.

**How I can get the BI type site created in SP OL?**

any other suggestions for this kind of requirements?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I can see business intelligent center template in my SharePoint online env, what's the SharePoint Plan of your account?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the business intelligent center template, it only exists some office 365 plans. Please see details in :[SharePoint Online Service Description](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819267.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for info @Matt, I am wondering where you are able to see the business intelligent center template in sharepoint online version?

I am trying to develop a business intelligent center template site in Microsoft SharePoint online version for customers and developers.

Comment: @nks, I'm using SharePoint Online 2013, enterprise plan

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately BI center in sharpoint online doesnt have any BI features available such as power pivot or power view,excel services and so on. it is just a simple site template.

We need to have E3 or E4 plan with additional power BI tools (20 $/user) license to have the BI features.